# Effect of ethanol on TRizol RNA extraction

Tags: rna, protocol

I added ethanol instead of chloroform to the cell suspension in Trizol. Can I still obtain my aqueous phase?

Comment: How much ethanol did you add?

Comment: I added 100 uL of etanol

Comment: To which amount of sample?

Comment: to 500 uL of cell suspension in Trizol

Comment: @polonio210 Can you edit that information in the comments into the body of your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is based on my experience in the lab and something like a best guess - it may or may not work. But given the fact that added 100µl of ethanol to 500µl of total volume and since water and ethanol mix completely, I would give it a shot.

I don't think that the ethanol would change the polarity of the solution so much that phase separation is inhibited. The only thing that I can image is the contamination of the aqueous phase with traces of phenol, so I would probably clean up more carefully and do an additional NaOAC/ethanol precipitation at the end of the procedure. If you expect a small pellet with little nucleic acids, add some glycogen to get a better outcome there. I would appreciate it, if you could comment on your experience (and the outcome) when you try to save you sample.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Oh yes, I will let you know!